# Mail from a Laravel application not working from Server; Works fine from local

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBMXQ.png)[image]

I have a Laravel application hosted in **Godaddy**. But when I tested the mail functionality, it gives the error

> "Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com
>   [Connection refused #111]"

The same application works fine in **localhost:8000**

I tried changing `MAIL_DRIVER` to `'sendmail'` and changed `PORTS` and `ENCRYPTION`. When using `'sendmail'` it doesn't show the error but I do not get the mail in the inbox. It goes straight to spam. That too after ~5 mins

Comment: Does GoDaddy allow you to connect to Google's SMTP server?  I'd start looking at GoDaddy's documentation regarding their firewall settings and their relationship with Google and Gmail.  I bet you will find information on this.

Comment: Thank you. Contacted GoDaddy regarding the issue. They simply told me to ask the question in Laravel forum.

Comment: Can you post the .env file used in your local setup, and your .env file you're running in production?

Comment: I added the SS of the .env file. It is the same file used in both local and production.

Comment: have you tried to less secure your account, this works for me and i don't know why i have to less secure my account for it to work, for gmail try it here https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/6260879?hl=en

Comment: Your MAIL_USERNAME and MAIL_PASSWORD are blank...  IF you purposefully removed it because you were covering up sensitive data, then awesome...  IF you did not, how does this work in your local environment?  Did you hardcode the username and password?  What method are you using to deploy your code onto production?  Are you pulling directly from a versioning system?  Is your .env file saved into your versioning system, or is it ignored?  There is a lot of information missing about the actual movement of files from your dev environment to production.

Comment: @EmekaOkaforYeah I did that. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelMiller I purposefully removed it. I used FTP to deploy my code into production. Also Thank you. It works when I change my MAIL_DRIVER to sendmail. Albeit it goes into spam and it is slow.